# Deploy Neo4j server in read-only mode

Tags: neo4j, server

Is it possible to deploy the **Neo4j server** *(version 2.3.2)* in **read-only** mode so that e.g. when using the data browser or Cypher console the database remains unchanged (thus having CREATE/UPDATE statements somewhat deactivated) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `read_only=true` in `conf/neo4j.properties`.